# Do linear functions, in addition to power law functions, have the property of scale invariance?

Tags: probability, statistics

I recently came across the concept of scale invariance in the context of power laws.

According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law#Scale_invariance):

> Given a relation $f(x)=ax^{-k}$, scaling the argument $x$ by a constant factor $c$ causes only a proportionate scaling of the function itself.

Suppose we have a simple linear equation $f(x) = 3x$

If we scale the argument, $x$, by a constant $c$, we have $f(cx)$ = $3cx$.

In this case, the value of the function is scaled by the same factor, $c$, as the argument was scaled by. Does this mean that $f(x) = 3x$ exhibits scale invariance?

Is the idea that it's more interesting that a power law is scale invariant since it is scale invariant *despite* it dealing with exponents that are not equal to 1?

Comment: The linear case is just $k = -1$.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I suspected, but wasn't sure if I was missing something. It just seems odd that a central definition of a power law is scale invariance. I suppose perhaps it's to help provide contrast to exponential functions, which don't exhibit scale invariance?